# Not knowing how to read a .TXT file in a secondary code of the main one - Python

Tags: python

this is my second post, I'm very grateful with everyone who helped me with my first post.

I will try to explain concisely what I am trying to do.

I have a main code, a folder called "letras" which contains 10 .txt files with a song inside each file (the first line is the artist or the name of the song) and finally I have a secondary code (which it is called by the main code) with which I have to work.

I'll go on to show the code of the secondary file so I can explain better.

```
from configuracion import *
import random
import math
import unicodedata

def lectura(archivo, letra, artistaYcancion): #se queda solo con los oraciones de cierta longitud
    #return (["artista 1","linea 1","linea 2"])
    artistaYcancion=archivo.readline(1)
    for lineas in archivo:
        letra.append(lineas)

def seleccion(letra):#elige uno al azar, devuelve ese y el siguiente
    #return (["linea 1","linea 2"])
```

What I have to do in these two functions that are called by the main code is to read the .txt files that are the songs, and that on the screen it shows a random line of the lyrics and the next.

The "lectura" function is the one that is responsible for reading the .txt in the list folder, I tried to do what you see in the code but from what I see it is not right and also I do not know how to do to restrict the length of the sentences.

The "seleccion" function is the one that is responsible for displaying two sentences of the lyrics of the song on the screen, the first sentence is randomly selected and the second sentence is the one that follows the first.

I think that would be all, if there is any doubt or something is not very helpful, please comment and try to explain as well as possible, most of the things that are being asked are likely to be in the main program already configured by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the file and return lines as list try this:

```
lines = open('filename.txt', 'r').readlines()
```